# How to remember checkbox input in PHP Forms

Tags: php, validation, forms

For usability purposes I like to set up my form fields this way:

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$message  = $_POST['message'];

?>

<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" />

<textarea name="message"><?php echo $message; ?></textarea>
```

This way if the user fails validation, the form input he entered previously will still be there and there would be no need to start from scratch.

My problem is I can't seem to keep check boxes selected with the option that the user had chosen before (when the page refreshes after validation fails). How to do this?

Answer (score 5):

My first suggestion would be to use some client-side validation first.  Maybe an AJAX call that performs the validation checks before continuing.

If that is not an option, then try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="subscribe" <?php echo (isset($_POST['subscribe'])?'checked="checked"':'') ?> />
```

So if `subscribe` is = 1, then it should select the box for you.

Comment: It's checked="checked" not selected

Comment: Fixed, sorry.  I was thinking <option> tags.

Comment: This will produce an array index undefined warning if the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: @Asaph, good point, I changed it to isset.  If the value is sent via POST, it HAS to be 1 (meaning checked).  Therefore, we can just check to see if the key exists.

Comment: @Johnson You know that you can use the value="" attribute with the checkbox too? So it doesn't have to be 1, but no matter what the value is, and if it's checked, then it's at least set . So the isset() is a good way to go

Answer (score 3):

For Example, consider the following code for checkbox :-

```
<label for="course">Course:</label>
PHP<input type="checkbox" name="course[]" id="course" <?php if ((!empty($_POST["course"]) && in_array("PHP", $_POST["course"]))) {
echo "checked";
} ?> value="PHP" />
```

Then, this would remember the checkbox of "PHP" if it is checked, even if the validation for the page fails and so on for "n" number of checkboxes as shown below:-

```
<label for="course">Course:</label>
        PHP<input type="checkbox" name="course[]" id="course" <?php if ((!empty($_POST["course"]) && in_array("PHP", $_POST["course"]))) {
echo "checked";
} ?> value="PHP" />
        HTML<input type="checkbox" name="course[]" id="course" <?php if     ((!empty($_POST["course"]) && in_array("HTML", $_POST["course"]))) {
echo "checked";
} ?> value="HTML" />
        CSS<input type="checkbox" name="course[]" id="course" <?php if ((!empty($_POST["course"])     && in_array("CSS", $_POST["course"]))) {
echo "checked";
} ?> value="CSS" />
        Javascript<input type="checkbox" name="course[]" id="course" <?php if     ((!empty($_POST["course"]) && in_array("Javascript", $_POST["course"]))) {
echo "checked";
} ?> value="Javascript" />
```

And most importantly, do not forget to declare the "course" variable as an array at the start of the code as shown below :-

```
$course = array();
```

Comment: that is a neat solution but  you are not actually using an array $course, so there is no need to worry about declaring it!

Answer (score 1):

I have been battling how to create sticky check box (that is able to remember checked items any time you visit the page). Originally, I get my values from a database table. This means that my check box value is entered to a column on my db table.

I created the following code and it works just fine. I did not want to go through that whole css and deep coding, so...

**CODE IN PHP**

```
$arrival = ""; //focus here.. down
if($row['new_arrival']==1) /*new_arrival is the name of a column on my table that keeps the value of check box*/
{$arrival="checked";}// $arrival is a variable
else
{$arrival="";};
echo $arrival;

<b><label for ="checkbox">New Arrival</label></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name ="$new_arrival" value="on" '.$arrival.' /> &nbsp;(Tick box if product is new) <BR><BR>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="somevar" value="1" <?php echo $somevar ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>/>
```

Also, please consider sanitising your inputs, so instead of:

```
$somevar = $_POST['somevar'];
```

...it is better to use:

```
$somevar = htmlspecialchars($_POST['somevar']);
```

Comment: I have to ask why so many downvotes for this.  It's a good answer, but just missing explanation and code tags. (use four spaces or `s to start code syntax)

Comment: I think it's because I had to edit it a load of times. I just bashed something out quickly without previewing it and had to correct it about 3 times. >_<

Comment: Why sanitizing when you're just checking if the value exists? No need.

Answer (score 0):

When the browser submits a form with a checked checkbox, it sends a variable with the name from the `name` attribute and a value from the `value` attribute. If the checkbox is *not* checked, the browser submits nothing for the checkbox. On the server side, you can handle this situation with [`array_key_exists()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php). For example:

```
<?php
$checkedText = array_key_exists('myCheckbox', $_POST) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="1"<?php echo $checkedText; ?> />
```

Using [`array_key_exist()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) avoids a potential array index undefined warning that would be issued if one tried to access `$_POST['myCheckbox']` and it didn't exist.

Comment: You can use **isset** instead, it's faster as it is a language construct and not a function.  The only case where you would need **array_key_exist** instead of **isset** is if the value of the array at that key was "null"  This will never happen in POST/checkbox data.

Answer (score 0):

You may add this to your form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" <?php echo isset($_POST['mycheckbox']) ? "checked='checked'" : "" ?> />
```

`isset` checks if a variable is set and is not null. So in this code, `checked` will be added to your checkbox only if the corresponding `$_POST` variable has a value..

Comment: -1 identical answer as mine.  And **checked** is not XHTML valid.  It needs to be **checked="checked"**

Comment: Corrected `checked` for xhtml compliance. Disclaimer: I didn't bother with xhtml compliance in the first place since the answer is intended to answer the question directly. Identical would mean you explained what `isset` does, which **you didn't**.

Answer (score 0):

My array has `name="radioselection"` and `value="1"`, `value="2"`, and `value="3"` respectively and is a radio button array... how to I check if the radio value is selected using this code
I tried:

```
<?php echo (isset($_POST['radioselection']) == '1'?'checked="checked"':'') ?> />
```